# What are the coefficients of the polynomial $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\dots(x+n)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> What are the coefficients of the polynomial $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\dots(x+n)$?

I found that the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ is $\sum_{1\leq m_1<\cdots<m_k\leq n} {\prod_{i=1}^k {m_i}}$ (in other words, this is the sum of the products of $k$ different numbers from $1,\dots,n$), but is there a more comfortable way to express it?

Comment: Look up "Stirling numbers of the first kind".